# c++/CLI c# dll event leads _stat to return with error

Tags: c++, events, command-line-interface

ifile is 0 in normal use cases.
ifile is -1 (ENOENT) when DoesFileExist() gets called from an EventHandler from a managed class.

Same method, file does exist, but different results.

What don't we understand about mixed mode event messaging?

```
BOOL DoesFileExist(CString sFile)
{
    struct _stat  c_file;   // structs for file operations
    errno_t err;
    int ifile = _stat( sFile, &c_file );
    if ( ifile EQ 0 )   // file exists.
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else    // ifile = -1, check the error type...
    {
         _get_errno( &err );
        if ( err NE ENOENT )
        {
            char tempchar[512];
            sprintf_s(tempchar,"Error in DoesFileExist = %d  File=",err);
            CString sError = tempchar + sFile;
            DEBUGMessage(sError);
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: The classic mistake is not specifying the full path to the file and then not counting on the working directory for the process pointing somewhere else.

Comment: Turns out that the method called via the EventHandler is called on a Worker Thread. Why would a FileCheck fail in a Worker Thread?

Comment: @Hanspassant - We have stepped through the code and verified that the full path is being used.

Comment: I dunno, look for #define EQ !=

Comment: he uses this way: #define EQ  ==

Comment: We have messaged it back to the Main Thread and it still is giving the same results. The file path is built up using the same methods so I have to keep digging.